# How does boosted exp. work?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

My Electabuzz which i traded for from my friend gains boosted exp. I want to know how this works, why it is happening, and if i can do the same with my other Pokémon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Electabuzz you got from your friend is receiving boosted experience *because* it was traded.** This is to encourage trading with others and over the Internet, though it comes with the caveat that if you don't have all 8 badges yet, the Pokémon may not obey your commands.

The exact boost in this case is probably `1.5x`, since you described it as coming from a friend, so I assume you both live in and have your games purchased from the same real-world country. If you got a Pokémon traded from another country (i.e., over the GTS), it would instead have a `1.7x` boost.

You can't get this same boost for Pokémon you've caught ("my other Pokémon"), but you can gain some other boosts in Generation IV:

- `1.5x` for being a Trainer battle (this is so common it's not marked as "boosted" by the in-game text)
- `1.5x` if holding the extremely rare (in Generation IV) [Lucky Egg](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience-affecting_item#Lucky_Egg)

[Source/More Info](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Experience_gain_in_battle)